# R: Split data in ggplot based on other factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a beginner with R so I don't have much experience. I ran into a problem when trying to split my scatterplot in groups based on infection status. My dataset consists of log transformed antibody levels *logapfhap2* in this example. Infection status *any Pf inf* is coded as Yes or No and gives information on if someone has been infected during the follow-up period. I am plotting timepoints (x) against antibody levels (y). For time point 1 and 14 I would like to make 2 groups based on infection status.

This is the main part of the code I use to plot the data without splitting in groups:

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_jitter(data=data2, aes(x='1', y=logapfhap2, colour='PfHAP2A')) + 
    geom_jitter(data=data2,aes(x='14', y=logbpfhap2, colour='PfHAP2B')) + 
    geom_jitter(data=TRC, aes(x='C', y=PfHAP2, colour='PfHAP2C'))
```

which results in this graph:

[image]

Then I tried to split it (I only show the first time point here) which returns an error.

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_jitter(data=data2[data2$any_Pf_inf=='Yes'], 
                aes(x='1inf', y=logapfhap2[data2$any_Pf_inf=='Yes'], 
                colour='PfHAP2A')) + 
    geom_jitter(data=data2[data2$any_Pf_inf=='No'], 
                aes(x='1un', y=logapfhap2[data2$any_Pf_inf=='No'], 
                colour='PfHAP2B'))
```

I wanted to create this graph [image] but I get this error:

> Error: Length of logical index vector must be 1 or 55, got: 482

Hope this is clear! Could anyone help me with this problem? Thanks!

EDIT
Not sure if this makes it clearer, but this is what my data looks like:
[image]
[image]

Comment: In ggplot2 you generally don't subset the `y` variable but instead subset the dataset and pass that to the `data` argument.   Add an example of your dataset to the question to get more concrete advice.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve], e.g., by adding the result of `dput(data2)` and `dput(TRC)`. Screenshots of data are pretty useless. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried some other things and I have solved it now!

```
ggplot()+ 
      geom_jitter(data=data2[data2$any_Pf_inf=='Yes',], 
          aes(x='1inf', y=logapfhap2, 
          colour='PfHAP2A')) + 
      geom_jitter(data=data2[data2$any_Pf_inf=='No',],
          aes(x='1un', y=logbpfhap2, 
          colour='PfHAP2B'))
```

Apparently you have to add a comma after [data2$any_Pf_inf=='Yes',] to extract rows instead of columns.